Simple but important question: how do you write down the formula for the probability density of data in general?
In machine learning many data can be thought of as generated from a probability density function (also called probability distribution).
But most probability textbook only discuss probability density function over 1D scalar numbers (or at least devotes most chapters on it). This causes me not to know how you write down probability density function for more than one random variable, especially with respect to the applications in ML.
For example, a common probability distribution over the set of numbers $x \in \mathbb{R}$ could be analytically written as,
$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} e^{-(x-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2}$$
Then a single real number data can be sampled as $X \sim f_X(x)$.
But most data are more than just a number. My question is: how do you write down the analytical formula for data that are more than 1D? For example, a vector of data, a matrix of data, an image, a video, so and so forth.
Here is what I think right now (please correct me if I am wrong):
If I have a vector of N-dimensional data, then I could put these PDF into a single vector as so,
$$
f_X(x) = \begin{bmatrix} 
 f_{X_1}(x_1) \\ f_{X_2}(x_2) \\ \vdots \\ f_{X_N}(x_N) 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
And vectors of data can be sampled from this PDF.
Is $f_X(x)$ constructed this way a valid probability density function?
If I have a matrix of N $\times$ M dimensional data, then I will put them into a matrix. I won't write down the matrix, but assume that each entry is $f_{X_{ij}}(x_{ij})$. I define $f_X(x) = (f_{X_{ij}}(x_{ij}))_{i= 1, \ldots, n, j = 1, \ldots, m}$. Then matrices of data could be generated from this PDF.
Is $f_X(x)$ constructed this way a valid probability density function?
Finally, the data written this way has no particular meaning other than a set of number. What if the data forms a type of image? It is common in ML to assume images are samples from PDF. Is it possible to write down the actual formula for the probability density for generating the image?

Assuming you are talking about a continuous distribution, the multivariate density is essentially the derivative of the multivariate cumulative distribution function.

If the univariate components of a multivariate random variable are independent of each other (often not the case), then the joint density is the product of the individual densities.  Otherwise it can get more complicated.

For a multivariate normal distribution of  $\mathbf{x}$ with mean  $\boldsymbol\mu$ (both vectors) with a positive-definite covariance matrix $\boldsymbol\Sigma$, the density can be written  $(2\pi)^{-k/2}\det (\boldsymbol\Sigma)^{-1/2} , \exp \left( -\frac{1}{2} (\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol\mu)^\mathrm{T} \boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf{x} - \boldsymbol\mu) \right)$

@Henry Are there multivariable uniform, Poisson, or other distributions?

Yes - suitably defined.  For example you could have a distribution uniformly distributed over some hypervolume; if the components were i.i.d over an interval then that would be over a hypercube.

We have thousands of posts about multivariate distributions that you could refer to for examples.
